# My svg keysplines aren't working

Tags: svg-animate

I'm new to svg and trying some things for fun. Here I want to animate an hexagon I made using a path tag. It works fine but I can't seem to get why I can't ease my transitions...
Here is my path :

```
<path id="hex4" style="display:block;" fill="#847b63" d="M 89.35,69 L 105.67,69 L 113.83,84 L 105.67,99 L 89.35,99 L 81.2,84 Z"/>
```

And there my animate :

```
<animate id="hexAnim4" dur="2s" attributeName="d" xlink:href="#hex4" begin="0s" repeatCount="indefinite" keytimes="0;0.5;1" calcmode="spline" to="M 89.35,69 L 105.67,69 L 113.83,84 L 105.67,99 L 89.35,99 L 81.2,84 Z" values="M 89.35,69 L 105.67,69 L 113.83,84 L 105.67,99 L 89.35,99 L 81.2,84 Z; M 84.32,60 L 110.7,60 L 123.89,84 L 110.7,108 L 84.32,108 L 71.13,84 Z; M 89.35,69 L 105.67,69 L 113.83,84 L 105.67,99 L 89.35,99 L 81.2,84 Z;" keysplines=".42 0 1 1;0 0 .59 1;"/>
```

I've seen that the usual problem with keysplines not working is that not the right number is set : it should be one less than the values and keytimes. I checked that and I do have 3 keytimes/values for 2 keysplines.
Anyway, I hope some of you guys will have an answer for me!
Thanks!